# Will reinstall macOS delete the current OS?

Tags: mac, catalina

Will the current OS be deleted after I reinstall the new version OS by `command+option+R`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes and no** 
The update will install new things and modify existing ones. Your data and all your programs should stay the same though, but depending on your update some programs (for example 32-bit) will stop working.

You can't just downgrade to/simultaneously use the older OS if thats what you'd be trying to do after upgrading.

Yet, with a [TimeMachine backup](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/revert-to-a-previous-macos-version-mh15216/mac) or a clean install you can get the older OS or the OS your computer shipped with.

Comment: Thank you so much, why this isn't mentioned in Apple's website?

Comment: I updatet my answer to be more precise

Comment: @Niing No sure what you are missing in Apple‘s doc, but reinstalling basically is a synonym for „replacing the currently installed OS with another (or the same) version“. If you want to use several OS versions in parallel, look for dual boot or use a VM.

Comment: @nohillside: Thanks for the information... I had doubt about this since I remembered after updating macOS the old version would occupied disk space and one has to manually delete it.

Comment: In short, since El Capitan, any reinstall behaves like an upgrade. Command+Option+R will behave like an upgrade, will preserve all users data. (considering you don't open disk utility nor change any partition stuff) - Just a Command+Option+R and folow the installation will preserve everything